# primarily opinion-based or too broad, or just a best practices question?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/670752/is-using-distro-bundled-lamp-the-best-choice) got closed as primarily opinion-based.  At the time the question got closed, I had almost completed a fairly substantial and I thought helpful answer for a new sysadmin, explaining why yes, he should use his distro's packages unless he had a good reason not to.  In short, it's a best practice.

A similar thing happened to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/670630/network-administrator-handover-document).  I myself voted to close it as too broad, and it was closed.  But before it was, Zoredache flagged it as a duplicate of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/160402/what-are-some-best-practices-when-taking-over-it-at-a-new-company), which was longstanding and had a couple of high-quality and highly voted, though admittedly broad, answers.  Again, it ended up being a best practices question.  Later someone voted to close that one too.

So, my questions:

1. Can we please reopen the first question?  I think it's actually a pretty good question for a new sysadmin (though probably a dup if I could find it).
2. Any suggestions for how to distinguish good best practice questions from other too broad or opinion-based questions?

Comment: Edit it so it's not asking "what's best," but "what do I need to consider"/"how do I pick."

Comment: Although I do have vague memories of a discussion a while back where it was concluded that we'd be sympathetic to "best practice" questions, particularly if answers were backed by evidence.

Answer (score 3):

The first one might be a duplicate to some others, but if you edit it and write a good answer, we might use this as a canonical target for this kind of question, which appears semi-regular from new users/admins. However, personally I would rather have a new question for this purpose though (maybe as community wiki), to avoid the situation with the [compromised server](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005) question which started as a normal question from an unsuspecting user.

I don't believe the second question is fixable, as the list of things to consider is potential endless and highly dependent on the specific environment. Also, I am not sure we should have an answer that would need to be *too broad* itself as a dupe target for a question that would be closed as *too broad* otherwise.

Comment: OK. I just posted a community wiki question as a candidate: http://serverfault.com/questions/671223/install-software-from-packages-or-build-it-from-source .